# SQL statement, nested in query with two keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE (ID1,ID2) IS IN (SELECT ID1,ID2 FROM TAB2)
```

ID1 and ID2 is two primary key for TAB1 and TAB2, 
we can do it with single primary key but how to do with 2 primary key

Comment: Just join on two criteria... `Select * From Tab1 t1 Join Tab2 t2 On t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 And t1.ID2 = t2.ID2`

Comment: If you remove the `IS` keyword it is valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: which SQL Server does not support

Comment: @Quassnoi: wow, I didn't expect that...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tab1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    tab2
        WHERE   tab2.id1 = tab1.id1
                AND tab2.id2 = tab1.id2
        )
```

Comment: `SELECT NULL` works in that context?  I would think you would need to at least `SELECT tab2.id1, tab2.id2 ...`

Comment: In exists or "not exists", its common to use "select null" or "select 0" or "select 1".  I use "select null" as well.  Quassnoi is correct. "Try it".